# PHPCoord TypeError when running example conversions

Tags: php, composer-php, typeerror, coordinates, autoload

I'm battling on trying to use [PHPCoord](https://phpcoord.net/) to convert different types of coordinates. I am new to composer and PHP libraries so could well be making basic mistakes. I had issues related to [Autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) which I've now resolved but I'm now facing errors of a different kind which could well be basic and due to my inexperience in this area.

I'm using the following example code taken direct from the [PHPCoord docs](https://phpcoord.net/en/v5.2.0/coordinate_conversions_easy.html):

```php
use PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Geographic2D;
use PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Projected;
use PHPCoord\GeographicPoint;
use PHPCoord\UnitOfMeasure\Angle\Degree;

// Converting from NAD83 to Florida State Plane
$from = GeographicPoint::create(
    Geographic2D::fromSRID(Geographic2D::EPSG_NAD83),
    new Degree(28.46),
    new Degree(-80.53),
    null
);
$toCRS = Projected::fromSRID(Projected::EPSG_NAD83_FLORIDA_EAST);
$to = $from->convert($toCRS); // $to instanceof ProjectedPoint
```

Above this I'm autoloading with:

```php
$theme_root = dirname(__DIR__, 1);
require_once $theme_root . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PHPCoord\GeographicPoint::create() must be an instance of PHPCoord\UnitOfMeasure\Angle\Angle, instance of PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Geographic2D given...

As the example code relates to North American geography I also added the optional add-on datapack: `datapack-northamerica`, though this had no effect.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Thing you have to update your composer package because `create()` has changed see:   https://github.com/dvdoug/PHPCoord/commit/7cf9e331ccc95d58af2a8b6c36fd7780ac361f03#diff-1e27734ba2aba0eb5c98455d5fed1f42e8c30e10c5048d7ad386ed321a49d613   The parameter order is now different, and may you have taken an example for the new release, but using an old release.

Comment: Looks like you could be right, despite downloading it via composer only yesterday when I run `composer show |grep php-coord` it's telling me it's version 4.7.0 and according to the changelog...

> The v4.x series is receiving basic maintenance only. All feature development takes place in v5.x.

I shall update now and see if this fixes the issues. Thanks so much!

Comment: Further update. I deleted the package and related files and re-installed, this time using:

`composer php-coord/php-coord "^5.2.0"`

The installation failed, reason given was that the latest package required PHP ^8 and I'm running 7.4.12.

I'll need to re-jig my set-up in MAMP.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this myself in the hope that anyone else struggling with [PHPCoord](https://github.com/dvdoug/PHPCoord) might find guidance.

As kindly pointed out by @Foobar I was using an older version of the library despite installing it recently using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). This was because composer had detected my version of PHP (7.4.12) and decided it didn't meet the criteria for the latest version of PHPCoord. I assumed I had the latest version and was trying to use code examples suitable only for PHPCoord version 5 and beyond but I was running version 4.x.

It's all slightly confusing as the documentation states:

> PHPCoord v4 is compatible with PHP 7.3+

However, the code examples are for PHPCoord v5 which needs PHP 8.0+.

My solution was to upgrade my PHP version to 8.x.

This removed the error outlined above, however I then got a new *insufficient memory* error which was rectified by [upping my MAMP memory limit](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/FAQ/PHP/Increase-the-PHP-memory-limit/) from 128M to 256M.

So to re-cap, my first issue was not including `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`

I then had minimum requirement issues due to running PHP 7.4.x and not version 8.x and was unknowingly running an outdated version of the library.

I then had insufficient memory allocation issues which I resolved by editing `php.ini` changing `memory_limit = 128M` to `memory_limit = 256M`.

Thanks for all the comments and help. I can now move on to converting OSGB references to Lat/Lon but will need to ensure the production host is running PHP version 8 and has a sufficient memory limit.